# How to set chef node "normal" attributes in Terraform

Tags: chef-infra, terraform

I have the following terraform file:

```
resource "aws_instance" "hazelcast" {
ami           = "ami-11aa8c74"
instance_type = "t2.micro"
key_name      = "demo_terraform"
security_groups = ["ssh"]
tags {
      Name = "chef node - hazelcast"
}
provisioner "chef" {
  environment     = "${var.chef_environment}"
  run_list        = "${var.chef_run_list_hazelcast}"
  node_name       = "hazelcast_node"
  server_url      = "https://${var.chef_server}/organizations/${var.chef_organization}"
  secret_key      = "${file("~/terraform/chef-repo/encrypted_data_bag_secret")}"
  recreate_client = true
  ssl_verify_mode = ":verify_none"
  user_name       = "${var.chef_username}"
  user_key        = "${file("~/terraform/chef-repo/.chef/${var.chef_username}.pem")}"
  version         = "${var.chef_client_version}"
  attributes_json = <<-EOF
  {
    "team": "Cloud",
    "install_mancenter": false,
    "hazelcast_version": "3.6.2-2",
    "max_heap_size": "1G",
    "min_heap_size": "1G"      }
}
connection {
  type     = "ssh"
  user = "ec2-user"
  private_key = "${file("/temp/basics/demo_terraform.pem")}"
  agent = false
}
}
resource "aws_eip" "hazelcast" {
  instance   = "${aws_instance.hazelcast.id}"
  depends_on = ["aws_instance.hazelcast"]
}
output "address_hazelcast" {
    value = "${aws_instance.hazelcast.public_ip}"
}
```

In the hazelcast recipe I use the normal attributes defined above to search for nodes with same characteristics:

```
nodes = search(:node, "role:lc_hazelcast AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment} AND team:#{node.team}")
```

and also I store the normal attributes in some variables like:

```
hazelcast_version=node.hazelcast_version
min_heap_size=node.min_heap_size
max_heap_size=node.max_heap_size
```

The problem is that when I run terraform apply, i get this error:

```
aws_instance.hazelcast (chef): NoMethodError
aws_instance.hazelcast (chef): -------------
aws_instance.hazelcast (chef): undefined method `team' for #
<Chef::Node::Attribute:0x00000003752350>
```

Saying that it cannot find any attribute I'm defining in my tf file.

How should I define normal attributes so those can be seen when the node is bootstrapped and it runs the run list?

What am I missing?
Thank you,
Gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be `node["team"]`. We deprecated the method syntax long ago and it was removed in Chef 13.

Comment: you were right on the spot, like always. Thank you!